# Singleton class throws C2653 error: is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, singleton

App.h:

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "RoomManager.h"

typedef unsigned int uint;

class App {

private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Event evt;

    uint screen_width = 0;
    uint screen_height = 0;

    sf::Clock deltaClock;
    float deltaTime = 0.0f;

    RoomManager& roomManager = RoomManager::GetInstance();

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> allDrawables;

    App() { }
    ~App() { }

public:
    static App& GetInstance() {
        static App instance;

        return instance;
    }

    void CreateWindow(uint width, uint height) {
        screen_width = width;
        screen_height = height;

        window.create(sf::VideoMode(screen_width, screen_height), "Point'n'click adventure");
    }

    void Update() {
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            deltaTime = deltaClock.restart().asSeconds();

            while (window.pollEvent(evt)) {
                if (evt.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            Draw();
        }
    }

    void ResizeScreen(uint width, uint height) {
        screen_width = width;
        screen_height = height;

        window.setSize(sf::Vector2u(screen_width, screen_height));
    }

    void AddDrawable(sf::Sprite& sprite) {
        allDrawables.push_back(sprite);
    }

    void Draw() {
        window.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < allDrawables.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(allDrawables[i]);
        }

        window.display();
    }
};

#endif
```

DrawableEntity.h:

```
#ifndef DRAWABLEENTITY_H
#define DRAWABLEENTITY_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "App.h"

class DrawableEntity {
private:
    sf::Texture backgroundTexture;
    sf::Sprite backgroundSprite;

public:
    DrawableEntity() {
        App::GetInstance().AddDrawable(backgroundSprite);
    }
    ~DrawableEntity() { }

    void LoadTexture(const std::string texturePath) {
        backgroundTexture.loadFromFile(texturePath);
        backgroundSprite.setTexture(backgroundTexture);
    }
};

#endif
```

RoomManager.h:

```
#ifndef ROOMMANAGER_H
#define ROOMMANAGER_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "Room.h"

class RoomManager {
    private:
        std::vector<Room> rooms;

    public:
        static RoomManager& GetInstance() {
            static RoomManager instance;

            return instance;
        }

        void AddRoom(Room room) {
            rooms.push_back(room);
        }
};

#endif
```

Room.h:

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "App.h"
#include "DrawableEntity.h"

class Room {
    private:
        DrawableEntity background;

    public:
        Room(const std::string backgroundTexturePath) {
            background.LoadTexture(backgroundTexturePath);
        }
        ~Room() { }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "App.h"

using namespace sf;

int main() {
    App& app = App::GetInstance();
    RoomManager& roomManager = RoomManager::GetInstance();

    app.CreateWindow(1920, 1080);

    roomManager.AddRoom(Room("room_0_background.jpg"));

    app.Update();

    return 0;
}
```

My idea here is that whenever I would create DrawableEntity object, it would automatically add its sprite to allDrawables vector in App. The above code throws me C2653 error saying that "'App' is not a class or namespace name". The error appears in DrawableEntity() constructor, at line where I call AddDrawable() method. It's been a while since I coded in C++ (now I code mostly in C#) and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218858/discussion-on-question-by-mentor93-singleton-class-throws-c2653-error-is-not-a).

Answer (score 0):

[Note: As, you haven't shared **DrawableEntity()** constructor code(I didn't find any) I am assuming your problem might be the following. If the following solution does not solve your issue, please share **DrawableEntity()** constructor code.]

You must have called AddDrawable() as following:

```
App& appInstance = App::GetInstance();

appInstance::AddDrawable(); // it is wrong
```

You shouldn't call like above

Rather do the following:

```
App& appInstance = App::GetInstance();

appInstance.AddDrawable(); // it is correct
```

**Edit(Possible solution, this must be happening in your code):**

I guess @drescherjm is right. Please, take a careful look at the code snippets below. I have tested some codes similiar like your code structure:

**so_test.cpp file:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "so_header.h"

int main() {
    A& objA = A::getInstance();
    int xa = objA.getX();
    printf("xa: %d\n", xa);

    B& objB = B::getInstance();
    int xb = objB.getX();
    printf("xb: %d\n", xb);
    return 0;
}
```

**so_header.h file:**

```
#ifndef CLASS_A

#define CLASS_A

#include <cstdio>
#include "so_header_2.h"

class A {
private:
    int x = 100;
    A(){}
public:
    static A& getInstance() {
        static A obj;
        return obj;
    }
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    void print() {
        B& objB = B::getInstance();
        int xb = objB.getX();
        printf("xb: %d\n", xb);
    }
};

#endif
```

**so_header_2.h:**

```
#ifndef CLASS_B

#define CLASS_B

#include <cstdio>
#include "so_header.h"

class B {
private:
    int x = 200;
    B(){}
public:
    static B& getInstance() {
        static B obj;
        return obj;
    }
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    void print() {
        A& objA = A::getInstance();
        int xa = objA.getX();
        printf("xa: %d\n", xa);
    }
};

#endif
```

When I compile so_test.cpp, I get the follwowing error(using mingw compiler):

```
In file included from so_header.h:6:0,
                 from so_test.cpp:2:
so_header_2.h: In member function 'void B::print()':
so_header_2.h:21:3: error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
   A& objA = A::getInstance();
   ^
so_header_2.h:21:6: error: 'objA' was not declared in this scope
   A& objA = A::getInstance();
      ^
so_header_2.h:21:13: error: 'A' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
   A& objA = A::getInstance();
```

The reason is in print function of A, A is calling B and in print function of B, B is calling A.

Your code structure follows a similiar pattern. Let's start from DrawableEntity.

```
> DrawableEntity calls App
> App calls RoomManager
> RoomManager calls Room
> Room calls App and DrawableEntity(notice, the order here. App is called before DrawableEntity, and so loop has come back to App)
> App calls RoomManager...and ...so on...
```

So, the loop is:

```
DrawableEntity -> App -> RoomManager -> Room -> App -> RoomManager -> ...
```

As, App is the start of the loop or the first object in the loop to be called, you're getting error recognizing "App" class...cause, you started declaring App, but you've never finished declaring it, and in the middle of declaring it, you are trying to use it. So, you're basically trying to use something that hasn't even seen the light of existence(An analogy could be: its still in womb, not born yet...).

This has happended with your code.

To solve your problem, you need to reorganize your code structure a bit. Just break the cycle(i.e. loop) of call dependency, and you'd be okay.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually called AddDrawable with '.', not with '::'.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be `App& appInstance = App::GetInstance()`?

Comment: @mentor93, don't call AddDrawable(); just check if u can get the instance properly i.e. write only App appInstance = App::GetInstance(); and also can u provide me the error log?

Comment: Sorry my bad, It should be with &. I forgot we're doing Singleton. Fixed it...

Comment: I did as you said: `DrawableEntity() { App& app = App::GetInstance(); }` and this gives me following errors: `'App': undeclared identifier`, `'app': undeclared identifier`, `'App': is not a class or namespace name`, `'GetInstance': identifier not found`. Just to be clear, I include App.h header in DrawableEntity.h file: `#include "App.h"`. Both files (App.h and DrawableEntity.h) are in the same directory.

Comment: @mentor93 Another, question: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how to check it :/ I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (Community edition).

Comment: @mentor93 check my edited answer. Its explains properly, why are you getting this error.

Comment: Thanks, I get now why these errors occur. But more importantly - how do I fix them?

Comment: Organize your code based on dependency...see which objects needs which object...draw the graph in a paper. try to resolve them, rather than creating cycle in a graph, see if u can make a DAG, or tree like structure of dependency...

Comment: You may be able to solve this by implementing `DrawableEntity()` in the cpp file instead of the header. I am not sure because there is more than 1 cycle of headers.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.